# Removing automatically generated links from SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, web, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to prevent a page in SharePoint (specifically a list view page) from automatically generating links from UNC file paths that are entered in a field.

This is entered into the field...

```
\\server\share\folder name\sub-folder name
```

This is the automatically generated resultant value of the field on the display page...

(the actual value on the list item is still correct)

```
<a href="file://\\server\share\folder">\\server\share\folder</a>&nbsp;name\sub-folder name
```

I have found some similar questions regarding removing mailto links that suggest using jQuery to accomplish this.  This is what I came up with thus far...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $("a[href^=file:]").each(function(){  
            var sFileShare = $(this).text();
            $(this).replaceWith(sFileShare);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I inserted this into the target page by adding a (hidden) CEWP and then putting the above code in as embedded code.  Thus far I see no result.

Is this a code issue?  Am I implementing it wrong?  Should I have stayed asleep this morning?  Taking all bets.

My bet is that I need to format the `$("a[href^=file:]")` bit more correctly but I'm not sure.